# How to avoid using !important here

Tags: html, css

I want to know how to avoid using !important. And i should use only css, html, bootstrap.

I was trying to use a lot of selectors classes and so on but none of this helped me

```
.btn:active
{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    background-color: #F05F44 !important;
    outline-color: #F05F44 !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border-color: #F05F44 !important;

}


.btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none; 
}
```

I thing that i should change one properties but i don't know which/

P. S. I apologize for the mistakes, I made them, due to the fact that I am Russian-speaking and wrote all this in a hurry.

Comment: Can you show us the [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Can I know, why you don't want to use !important ?

Comment: Increase the [specificity of your selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) so it will override Bootstrap's CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have to know how css selectors are working. The most of it you can find over here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

2 things are not described in here:

- 2 times same selector in different or same css-file. =>  When this happens it is al up to the order. file last loaded wins.
- Inline styling => inline styling can only be overridden using `!important`